# Is it possible to program in C++ for X11 Xlib instead of using C?

Tags: c++, x11, xlib, xorg

I am trying to figure out programming in C++ classes for X11, XLib application but constantly getting "Program received signal SIGSEGV Segmentation fault" when the following line hit the execution.
further execution stop n program crash!

```
   void
sysInfo::Create_Window (Display *dpy, int border_width)
{
    scrn = DefaultScreen (dpy);  // **ERROR hit on this line**
    win_width  = DisplayWidth (dpy, scrn);
    win_height = DisplayHeight (dpy, scrn);

    wmDeleteMsg = XInternAtom (dpy, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    /* Set up for window Manager Icon */
    win_icon = XInternAtom (dpy, "_NET_WM_ICON", False);
    cardinal = XInternAtom (dpy, "CARDINAL", False);


    /* create operque window  */
   win = XCreateSimpleWindow (dpy,
                               RootWindow (dpy, scrn),
                               0, 0,
                               win_width,
                               win_height,
                               border_width,
                               BlackPixel (dpy, scrn),
                               WhitePixel (dpy, scrn) );

    //wmHints ();                 // Window Manager Hints
    //sizeHints ();               // Window default size could be override
    //classHints ();              // Window class

    // set up exit proc for sudden exit
    XSetWMProtocols (dpy, win, &wmDeleteMsg, 1);
```

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible.  Please create a [mcve] to help people diagnose your bug.

Comment: Is it possible to demo?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to program in C++ for X11 Xlib instead of using C?

Yes, it is.

> constantly getting "Program received signal SIGSEGV Segmentation fault"

It is unclear in your example where `dpy` comes frome, but are you sure you have properly opened a display connection? If so, this example should work fine:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

Window win;

void Create_Window(Display* dpy, int border_width)
{
    int scrn = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    int win_width = DisplayWidth(dpy, scrn);
    int win_height = DisplayHeight(dpy, scrn);

    Atom wmDeleteMsg = XInternAtom(dpy, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    /* Set up for window Manager Icon */
    Atom win_icon = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_ICON", False);
    Atom cardinal = XInternAtom(dpy, "CARDINAL", False);

    /* create operque window  */
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy,
                              RootWindow(dpy, scrn),
                              0,
                              0,
                              win_width,
                              win_height,
                              border_width,
                              BlackPixel(dpy, scrn),
                              WhitePixel(dpy, scrn));

    // wmHints ();                 // Window Manager Hints
    // sizeHints ();               // Window default size could be override
    // classHints ();              // Window class

    // set up exit proc for sudden exit
    XSetWMProtocols(dpy, win, &wmDeleteMsg, 1);
}

int main()
{
    Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    if (dpy == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open display connection" << '\n';
        exit(1);
    }
    Create_Window(dpy, 1);
    XMapRaised(dpy, win);
    XSync(dpy, false);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    XDestroyWindow(dpy, win);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexey104, but the problem was a different issue. If you like I can send the piece of code for your review?